# How should I configure Spark to correctly prune Hive Metastore partitions?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I'm having an issues when applying partition filters to Spark (v2.0.2/2.1.1) DataFrames that read from a Hive (v2.1.0) table with over 30,000 partitions. I would like to know what the recommended approach is and what, if anything, I'm doing incorrectly as the current behaviour is a source of large performance an reliability issues.

To enable pruning, I am using the following Spark/Hive property:

```
--conf spark.sql.hive.metastorePartitionPruning=true
```

When running a query in spark-shell I can see the partition fetch take place with an invocation to [`ThriftHiveMetastore.Iface.get_partitions`](https://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r2.1.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/hive/metastore/api/ThriftHiveMetastore.Iface.html#get_partitions-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-short-), but this unexpectedly occurs without any filtering:

```
val myTable = spark.table("db.table")
val myTableData = myTable
  .filter("local_date = '2017-09-01' or local_date = '2017-09-02'")
  .cache

// The HMS call invoked is:
// #get_partitions('db', 'table', -1)
```

If I use a more simplistic filter, partitions are filtered as desired:

```
val myTableData = myTable
  .filter("local_date = '2017-09-01'")
  .cache

// The HMS call invoked is:
// #get_partitions_by_filter(
//   'db', 'table',
//   'local_date = "2017-09-01"',
//   -1
// )
```

The filtering also works correctly if I rewrite the filter to use range operators instead of simply checking for equality:

```
val myTableData = myTable
  .filter("local_date >= '2017-09-01' and local_date <= '2017-09-02'")
  .cache

// The HMS call invoked is:
// #get_partitions_by_filter(
//   'db', 'table',
//   'local_date >= '2017-09-01' and local_date <= '2017-09-02'',
//   -1
// )
```

In our case, this behaviour is problematic from a performance perspective; call times are in the region of 4 minutes versus 1 second when correctly filtered. Additionally, routinely loading large volumes of`Partition` objects onto the heap per query ultimately leads to memory issues in the metastore service.

It seems as though there is a bug around the parsing and interpretation of certain types of filter constructs, however I've not been able to find a relevant issue in the Spark JIRA. Is there a preferred approach or specific Spark version where filters are correctly applied for all filter variants? Or must I use specific forms (e.g. range operators) when constructing filters? If so, is this limitation documented anywhere?

Comment: Raised a ticket in Spark JIRA [SPARK-22247](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-22247)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not found a preferred way of querying besides rewriting the filter as described in my (OP) question. I did find that spark has improved support for this and it looks like my case is addressed in Spark 2.3.0. This is the ticket fixing the problem I found: [SPARK-20331](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20331)